# Getting script exit status code in php

Tags: php, exit-code

Is there anyway to get the exit status code for a php script run in the background via exec($cmd, $output, $exitCode)?

For example:

```
exec('php script.php &', $output, $exitCode);
```

If the trailing '&' isn't included then $exitCode works as expected, it's always 0 otherwise.

Comment: Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533675/php-exec-return-value-for-background-process-linux

Comment: not positive, but i think if it is running in the background, then your code moves on before the called script finishes execution, so there is no way to get the returned status code.

Comment: The '0' you get probably means that the process was successfully sent to background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anybody that finds themselves here, my solution was to make a php script that takes a script as an argument.  The new script is called to the background and handles exit statuses appropriately.

For example:

```
$cmd = 'php asynchronous_script.php -p 1';
exec("php script_executor.php -c'$cmd' &");
```

The second script looks something like

```
$opts = getOpt('c:');
$cmd = rtrim($opts['c'], '&');
$exitCode = 0;
$output = '';

exec($cmd, $output, $exitCode);

if ($exitCode > 0) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Aren't you removing `&` in the second script? Meaning you are not running a background process in either case? You probably meant to run the first script in the background... probably.

Comment: @Khez It's been a while since I posted this, but I think you're right, the original solution had a hard coded & in the first exec() call, and removed it from the second so it could deal with the exit codes.

Comment: no worry, was searching for something similar (unrelated to background processes), read the accepted answer and felt the need to point out possible issues...

Answer (score 5):

I found something that is probably quite equivalent to Pradeep's solution. Someone posted about this on the function's documentation page.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#101506